# Alfresco Angular UI & Custom Spring Boot Back-end

Tags: java, angular, maven, spring-boot, alfresco

I found that Alfresco has an Angular UI([Alfresco Angular Components](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-ng2-components)) that works with alfresco platform module(generated with `mvn archetype:generate -Dfilter=org.alfresco:`).

It's possible to integrate a spring-boot application with alfresco platform to provide for the angular app to consume the alfresco API and to be able to create custom Spring REST Controllers to be consumed via custom functionalities in the UI and everything to be done from the same server container?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Alfresco platform would run separately from your Spring Boot app in its own WAR.

Also note that the Alfresco platform needs to be version 5.2 or higher to work with the Alfresco Developer Framework (ADF), which is what Alfresco calls the offering that includes the Angular components.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is the best way to create the communication between a Spring Boot app and the alfresco platform: via Alfresco Java client or OpenCMIS ?

Comment: There is not a single best way to do it. For some things, OpenCMIS will be sufficient. For others, you might want to hit the Alfresco REST API or custom web scripts with an HTTP client from Java code, and, in some cases, you might be able to get by with hitting the REST API from JavaScript, either from your own calls or using the Alfresco JS library. It really depends on your needs. The good news is there are lots of options.